# Detecting and launching an external application from within a Windows Phone 7.1/7.5 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-phone-7.1

I need to write an application that can detect if the "Bing - Get me there" application is installed on the current phone and if so, launch it.

Is this possible? The app would need to do this for other external applications as well, so a generic method or interface for this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Applications run in a sandbox on Windows Phone and there is no way to tell if other applications are installed unless you are writing both of them and you use a method to announce to other applications that you are installed and they know how to read that announcement.

2 approaches to such announcements would be:

1. Have both (all) apps synchronise with a web server and report which devices they have been installed on. The apps can the query which other apps have been installed on that device.
2. Have all apps write a file to a location where all apps can access. The only place to do this is the PicturesLibrary so you have to embed the identifier in the name of the image or in its contents and be able to query all images to identify the other installed apps. The user could manually delete any images you create in this way though.

Beware, neither method can tell if the other app has subsequently been uninstalled though so this is far from foolproof.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that. 
Applications on Windows Phone run in complete isolation, and can not act with other applications, other than some highly specialized apps (i.e. for playing media).