# Windows Phone, Navigate to MusicPlayer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing WP application, part of which is to play/stream audio files.

I didn't wanted to create my own page to display info of current playing track, so I decided to use Built-in Music's player, using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer class I created playlists and queued playback. It all works fine, but now I need to navigate to MusicPlayer, when user taps on track in my app, and that's the part I've no idea what to do.

I've tried to navigate to MusicPlayer using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.MediaPlayerLauncher, but it's not an option, because it...

1. Needs to receive media location in IsolatedStorage, which means
   streaming is impossible
2. Gets one media at a time, so no playlists
3. I guess I can't navigate without changing track(or starting over)

**Is there any way to navigate to Built-in Music Player's Now Playing page, without interrupting playback?**

Answer (score 0):

I think these questions might be helpful/related to what you're looking for:

1. [Detecting and launching an external application from within a Windows Phone 7.1/7.5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681968/detecting-and-launching-an-external-application-from-within-a-windows-phone-7-1)
2. [Launching other applications in Windows phone 7 Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042353/launching-other-applications-in-windows-phone-7-programatically)

In short, it doesn't seem like third-party apps have permission to access other apps on the phone, probably for security reasons.